# Excel VBA Looping rows does not work, Run-time error '1004'

Tags: vba, excel, loops, for-loop

I am trying to bcreate a loop that goes thru rows in a selected range in excel and output's a score to each row, but I get this error referring to the firt line in the for loop (setting VARIABLE1). If I replace the .Range("A") with "A2" then I get an output but only for the first row naturally. How do I make it so that the code will loop each row?
The code:

```
Dim rng As Range
Dim Final_risk_score
Set rng = Worksheets("sheet name").Range("A1:Z100")

For Each Row In rng.Rows
    VARIABLE1 = Worksheets("sheet name").Range("A")
    VARIABLE2 = Worksheets("sheet name").Range("K")
    VARIABLE3 = Worksheets("sheet name").Range("J")
    VARIABLE4 = Worksheets("sheet name").Range("W")
    VARIABLE5 = Worksheets("sheet name").Range("G")
    VARIABLE6 = Worksheets("sheet name").Range("N")
    VARIABLE7 = Worksheets("sheet name").Range("X")
    VARIABLE8 = Worksheets("sheet name").Range("Y")
    VARIABLE9 = Worksheets("sheet2").Range("N7")

    Final_score = Score_calculations(VARIABLE1, VARIABLE2, VARIABLE3, VARIABLE4, VARIABLE5, VARIABLE6, VARIABLE7, VARIABLE8, VARIABLE9)
    Worksheets("sheet name").Range("Z").Value = Final_score
Next Row
```

Comment: What is error 1004? What have you tried?

Comment: A `Range` needs more than just `"A"` - it needs something like `"A1"`

Comment: thank you @ScottCraner for your answer! This works now!

Answer (score 2):

First do not use Row as a variable. Use something like `Rw`.

Then change `.Range("A")` to:

```
 .Cells(Rw.Row,"A")
```

do that for all the ranges. The range must have a row attached.

You could also do:

```
 .Range("A" & Rw.Row)
```

So:

```
Dim Rw as Range
Dim rng As Range
Dim Final_risk_score
Set rng = Worksheets("sheet name").Range("A1:Z100")

For Each Rw In rng.Rows
    VARIABLE1 = Worksheets("sheet name").Cells(Rw.Row,"A")
    VARIABLE2 = Worksheets("sheet name").Cells(Rw.Row,"K")
    VARIABLE3 = Worksheets("sheet name").Cells(Rw.Row,"J")
    VARIABLE4 = Worksheets("sheet name").Cells(Rw.Row,"W")
    VARIABLE5 = Worksheets("sheet name").Cells(Rw.Row,"G")
    VARIABLE6 = Worksheets("sheet name").Cells(Rw.Row,"N")
    VARIABLE7 = Worksheets("sheet name").Cells(Rw.Row,"X")
    VARIABLE8 = Worksheets("sheet name").Cells(Rw.Row,"Y")
    VARIABLE9 = Worksheets("sheet2").Range("N7")

    Final_risk_score= Score_calculations(VARIABLE1, VARIABLE2, VARIABLE3, VARIABLE4, VARIABLE5, VARIABLE6, VARIABLE7, VARIABLE8, VARIABLE9)
    Worksheets("sheet name").Cells(Rw.Row,"Z").Value = Final_risk_score
Next Row
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the loop to this:

```
Dim myRow As Range
For Each myRow In rng.Rows
    With Worksheets("sheet name")

        VARIABLE1 = .Range("A" & myRow.Row)
        VARIABLE2 = .Range("K" & myRow.Row)
        'etc
    End With
Next Row
```

Thus it would work, as far as you are referencing the Range correctly.